# Listing preprints on CV (undergrad)

Tags: publications, paper-submission, cv, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I'm now a second year math student at a top uni, and in the summer of my first year, I was a part of a small research team where we proved various new results related to Random Matrix Theory and wrote 2 papers on them. Now those papers are up on arXiv, but it hasn't been accepted to a peer-reviewed journal yet. My question is that when I'm applying for summer research programs etc should I list these as "preprints" on my CV even if they haven't been accepted to a journal yet?

Comment: What do you mean by "even"?  Preprint = not accepted publication.

Comment: (in case it isn't clear from the duplicate, which explains how different "levels" of work are considered, yes you should list preprints on your CV, assuming they are of high-quality and representative of your academic abilities)

Comment: Related: [arXiv Papers vs. Peer Reviewed Papers; How Does Admission Committee Evaluate?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/45972/68109)

Answer (score 4):

If a publication is either published or accepted at a journal, list it under your "normal" publications - if you want, you can choose the caption "Peer-reviewed publications".  If it is not published yet, write "accepted at $JOURNAL", or similar.

If the paper is still under review, or otherwise not published at a peer-reviewed journal, but available as a preprint, list it under "Preprints".